# Traefik Load-balancing methods

Tags: performance, traefik-ingress

I use traefik.io/v1.7, and want to change the default Load-balancing [method](https://docs.traefik.io/v1.7/basics/#load-balancing) to `drr`

For tests, I configure 2 microservices, one returns the instant response, second returns answers in a serials manner with an interval of 1 second

`Wrr` test:
[image]
[image]

Results:

microservice 1: 637 responses, (queue length: 278, unanswered requests)

microservice 2: 522 responses

`Drr` test:
[image]
[image]

Results:

microservice 1: 606 responses, (queue length: 217, unanswered requests)

microservice 2: 13399 responses

Where can I find a detailed description of the `drr` algorithm, and maybe some extra configurations?

Why did the requests start to be redirected to the faster microservice only after ~4 minutes?

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be a feature request to add more configuration options to DRR load balancing - https://github.com/traefik/traefik/issues/3745